# Converting WRF files to raster stacks! Projection

Tags: r

I have WRF output netCDF files with 1499*749*91 dimensions produced with "Mercator" projection over the Horn Of Africa. I would like to convert netCDF files into raster stack to undertake further analysis. I have been trying different options but it didn't work for me. I am getting values on wrong locations. I require help in this regards and any help is much appreciated.
Here is the code :

```
ro_rast <- nc_open("wrf_CAM0_daily_pre.nc") 
pre <- ncvar_get(ro_rast, "pre") ro_rast$dim$lon$vals -> lon ro_rast$dim$lat$vals -> lat ro_rast$dim$ncl2$vals -> time rm(ro_rast) 
r1_brick <- brick(pre, xmn=min(lat), xmx=max(lat), ymn=min(lon), ymx=max(lon), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0")) 
names(r1_brick)<- seq(as.Date('2018-06-01'), as.Date('2018-08-31'), 'days') 
# convert names of layer into date par(mar = c(2, 2, 2, 2)) 
cam1_mean <- t(calc(r1_brick, sum)) 
# seasonal sum precipitation
 cam1 <- flip(cam1_mean, direction = 2)

library(akima)# intepolation 

lonlat_reg <- expand.grid(lon = seq(min(lon), max(lon), length.out = 1499), 
                          lat = seq(min(lat), max(lat), length.out = 749))
test <- interp(x = as.vector(lon), y = as.vector(lat), z = as.vector(pre), 
               xo = unique(lonlat_reg[,"lon"]), yo = unique(lonlat_reg[,"lat"]), 
               duplicate = "error", linear = FALSE, extrap = FALSE)

test <- interp(x = as.vector(lon), y = as.vector(lat), z = as.vector(pre), 
               nx = 1499, ny = 749, linear = FALSE, extrap = FALSE)

# turn into a raster
test_ras <- raster(test)
```

Comment: Budusa Wara, welcome on SO. Could you give examples of the options you tried and the difficulties you encountered so that we can help?

Comment: Hi Markos, could you edit your question (perhaps with an EDIT: label so people know it's been edited) and post the code from your comment into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach would be

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("wrf_CAM0_daily_pre.nc")
```

It that does not work, can you point us to the file you are using?
I get this error message (you should have added that to your question).

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) : 
  cells are not equally spaced; you should extract values as points
```

I checked the file, and in this case, the raster is not a regular grid. The size of the cells changes with latitude. The file does not provide the x and y values of the coordinate reference system used. So the best you can do is extract these values as points, as you were doing, using the interface of the `ncdf4` or another package. You can then not directly make a RasterBrick. But you do so using `rasterize` or `interpolate`.

Comment: Thank you for your support. The standard approach reads the file but the location of values was not on the appropriate location. I tried functions like transpose () and flip but couldn't get on the required position. The work is over the Horn of Africa (include Sudan, S.Sudan, Ethiopia, Djibouti, Kenya, Somalia, Eretria). I pointed example file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dCtLrkwpHTldcz6xdwuPbGSV0Wl7G0wP/view. Thank you for your kind support once again.

Comment: I cannot download the file. Can you change the permissions?

Comment: sorry, I changed the permission

Comment: Could you able to download or still there is a problem. Let me know. I am still waiting eagerly for your support @Robert Hijmans. The code I provided worked for a single layer but stack cannot be located in the intended place of the value. I think the problem is caused due to the projection and I also failed to convert file into CF file type.

Comment: I do not have access to the file

Comment: I have changed permission https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/my-drive thank you  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1poX7IFz74z9Erc6fHy2AKXIs-uptPRKs/view you can have option here

Comment: It says "You need access. Ask for access, or switch to an account with access."

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1poX7IFz74z9Erc6fHy2AKXIs-uptPRKs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you -Robert Hijmans, Yet, how does rasterization works?

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem can you give me your expert hand. I edited the code used for interpolation based on akima package. I would like to create a raster stack from the file with 92 layers.

Comment: It is probably best to ask a new question about interpolation. If you do that, please include some simple example data. See, e.g., raster::interpolate.